# Manipulating Text after Get-Content

Tags: powershell, text

I have a log file that I have to scan every 5 minutes for specific keywords - specifically "Order Failed"  then capture the lines around that.  I have that part programmed with no issues.  The rest of the log entries don't matter. I'm able to use the command:

```
[string] $readFile = get-content c:\test\friday.log | select-String -pattern '(order.*failed)' -context 1,7
```

which outputs:

> Message: Order submission failed.
>
> ---
>
> Timestamp: 4/1/2016 4:05:09 PM
>
> Severity: Error
>
> Message: Modifier not authorized for parent item
>
> ---
>
> Message: Order submission failed.
>
> ---
>
> Timestamp: 4/1/2016 4:18:15 PM
>
> Severity: Error
>
> Message: Modifier not authorized for parent item
>
> ---

Which is exactly what I want.  My problem is trying to read through the above output and store the "Timestamp" into a variable that I can manipulate.
The first challenge is the "Timestamp" time is written in UTC time and we are located in the Pacific Time Zone.
The second challenge is I need to compare the "Timestamp" time to the current time and store that as an integer.  We only want to report errors that are within 5 minutes of the current time.

My current code only grabs the first "Timestamp" entry since I hard-coded it:

```bsh
[string] $readFile = get-content c:\test\friday.log | select-String -pattern '(order.*failed)' -context 1,7
$fileArray = $readFile.Split(“`n”)
[dateTime] $TrimTime = $fileArray[3].trim("Timestamp: ")
[dateTime] $currentTime = get-date
[int32] $getMinutes = (new-timespan -start $TrimTime -end $currentTime).minutes
```

I don't know how to loop through the output of the Get-content - to check for all of the Timestamps - we only want to report errors that are within 5 minutes of the current time.

Answer (score 2):

Don't cast your matches to a string right away.

```
$readFile = get-content c:\test\friday.log | select-String -pattern '(order.*failed)' -context 1,7
```

If you leave the `MatchInfo` objects intact for the time being you can extract the timestamps from the aftercontexts like this:

```
$readFile | ForEach-Object {
  $_.Context.AfterContext | Where-Object {
    $_ -match 'timestamp: (\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2} [ap]m)'
  } | ForEach-Object {
    $timestring = $matches[1]
  }
}
```

Use the [`ParseExact()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) method to convert the matched substring to a `DateTime` value:

```
$fmt     = 'M\/d\/yyyy h:mm:ss ttK'
$culture = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture

$timestamp = [DateTime]::ParseExact("${timestring}Z", $fmt, $culture)
```

The `Z` that is appended to `$timestring` indicates the UTC timezone and the trailing `K` in the format string makes the method recognize it as such. The result is automatically converted to your local time. If you need the time in UTC: append `.ToUniversalTime()` to the method call.